# TryUpdateModel not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project that will allow users to perform batch edits on the attributes of objects. The implementation is in a sort of "wizard" like form with four phases to the process as follows:

1. "Select the attributes you want to edit" - the first page will present the user with a list of checkboxes representing each of the attributes they want to edit. The user should check the attributes they wish to edit and select "Continue".
2. "Edit the selected attributes" - the second page will present the user with a list of distinct "editors" which will be unique for each of the attributes they selected on the first page.
3. "Review your changes" - this page will allow the user to review the changes they've made to the attributes they selected.
4. "Submit your changes" - this page will actually submit the information about the edits the user wishes to make to the selected attributes against the selected collection of objects.

Fairly straight-forward.

As I mentioned, the "editor" will be unique to each attribute, and could have any combination of different controls on it. Once a user has made their edits and the application posts that information to the "Review" page is where I'm currently having my problem.

We've developed the concept of an "EditorWorker" class that is unique to each attribute, which is responsible for generating the ViewModel necessary for each editor, but is also responsible for creating/returning (within the "Review" page controller action) an object that is the "model" object for the editor that the post data can be bound to, which can then be use to display the edited data for review. This object should have properties that match up with the IDs of the controls in the editor so that model binding can occur.

I've got the "EditorWorker" creating and returning the class needed, but for some reason, when I call `TryUpdateModel` and pass in that class, its properties aren't getting populated as a result of that method call as I would expect them to. I have verified that the values are in the posted FormCollection. Below is the code for my controller action where I'm attempting to do this. If someone can help me understand why `TryUpdateModel` isn't working in this scenario, I would be very appreciative.

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Review(ReviewBatchViewModel model)
{
    var selectedAttributes = GetSelectedAttributes(model.SelectedAttributeIds.Split(',').Select(i => Int64.Parse(i)).ToArray());
    var workers = new List<IEditorWorker>();
    var reviewData = new Dictionary<ViewAttribute, IEditData>();
    foreach (var attribute in selectedAttributes)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.EditorWorker)) // If there is no EditorWorker defined for this object, move on...
        {
            var worker = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}.{1}", EditorWorkerNamespace, attribute.EditorWorker)));
            var attributeEditData = ((IEditorWorker)worker).LoadEditData();
            if (TryUpdateModel(attributeEditData))
                model.EditData.Add(attributeEditData); // model.EditData is a List<IEditData> that will be iterated on the Review page
            reviewData.Add(attribute, attributeEditData);
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}

// ReviewBatchViewModel.cs
public class ReviewBatchViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ReviewBatchViewModel() { EditData = new List<IEditData>(); }

    public string SelectedAttributeIds { get; set; }
    public List<ViewAttribute> SelectedAttributes { get; set; }
    public List<IEditData> EditData { get; set; }
}

// IEditData.cs
public interface IEditData
{
}

// BroadcastStatusEditData.cs
public class BroadcastStatusEditData : IEditData
{
    public int BroadcastStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I totally understand that this controller action is incomplete in its current state. I'm presently working on just trying to get those EditData objects populated correctly before I move on. As mentioned, any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE: With regards to @mare's comment, I should have explained that part more clearly, sorry. The call to TryUpdateModel actually *is* returning true, but the fields on the model object being passed into it aren't actually being populated from the values that have been confirmed present in the posted form data. The model object being passed into the call is not a List, its just a poco. The resulting, ultimately hopefully populated model object is then being added to a List collection of model objects that will then be used for displaying the posted data for review on the Review page. I'm not loading anything from a datastore at all. Unique editors for each selected attribute are being rendered to the Edit screen, and I'm attempting to capture the edit values for display on a Review screen prior to submitting the batch of edits to a service. Hopefully that's more clear. Thanks.

UPDATE 2: I've included the definition of the `ReviewBatchViewModel` class as requested by @mare in the comments. The use of the `var` keyword in most cases in this code sample is largely due to the fact that the methods that are populating those variables is going to be returning an object of a different type for each attribute selected, so I never know exactly what its going to be at runtime (although it will always implement an interface, in this case either `IEditorWorker` and/or `IEditData`). There is a single class in the Model called "Attribute". The provided code sample has three variables relative that class: 1) `SelectedAttributeIds` is a comma-separated list of the Id's of the attributes that the user has selected to edit, which gets passed from the Edit page to the Review page via hidden field, 2) `selectedAttributes` is a collection of the actual Attribute objects that correspond to those Ids that I can work with, and 3) `attributeEditData` is an instance of the `IEditData` class specific to each given attribute that I'm attempting to bind the posted data from the Edit page to.

Hopefully this additional information clears things up even more.

Comment: TryUpdateModel() returns true if succeeded and false if it did not. What do you mean by not working? Does that mean it is returning false? If so, you might want to try UpdateModel() and since this one does not return true or false, it will most likely fail with an Exception and then you might use this exception's details to figure out what's wrong. I don't think that UpdateModel() and TryUpdateModel() will work with a List. Besides I do not get it why you load up the EditData from the datastore, then update it from the Model and then store this updated data back to the Model. ?

Comment: @mare - please see my updates in response to your question. Thanks.

Comment: could you post the relevant portions of ReviewBatchViewModel and attributeEditData class (whatever it is, which, by the way, reminds me that it would be easier to understand if you could also explicitely declare your variables instead of using var's)? I think that TryUpdateModel is not working because it has trouble creating mappings between the ReviewBatchViewModel and the type of attributeEditData's.

Comment: maybe it's just me but I'm having trouble understanding the code since there's multiple variables and classes having the word "attribute" in it..;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Josh, you were very helpful in helping me understand why TryUpdateModel wasn't working for me, and I appreciate that. Unfortunately, I think the larger issue here was that fact that I (not exactly sure which) was either unable or unwilling to try to document all of the details of the requirements for the problem I'm trying to solve here, which I think made it difficult for anyone to be able to provide much meaningful input. The biggest problem for us is that, because we have no idea until runtime which attributes a user has selected for editing, we don't know which objects we'll be working with in the context of these controller actions, or what their types will be. The one place that we safely can work with known data and types, is within the context of each of the unique EditorWorker objects, which is where I've chosen to do the heavy lifting here.

I was hoping and attempting to take advantage of all of the heavy lifting that MSFT has done for us within the MVC framework to handle model binding, but I've come to the conclusion at this point that I don't think that's going to work for us. The solution that I've come up with at this point, is to allow the `LoadEditData` method of the `EditorWorker` classes handle loading up the `EditData` classes for for me. As each `EditorWorker` class is unique to, and has knowledge of the attribute that it is associated with. The problem I was having originally was that I was letting the `EditorWorker.LoadEditData` method just return an empty instance of the specific type of `EditData` class that I needed for the attribute I was currently working with, and let the MVC framework handle model binding to that object for me. That wasn't working because that method is designed to return an object of type `IEditData`, and I never really knew exactly what type it was that I was currently working with, so I had no way of specifying the type in the call to either of the typed methods: `TryUpdateModel<T>` or `UpdateModel<T>`.

So the solution I've come up with, and am going with at least for now (re-education and/or refactoring may very well change this in the future, who knows) is to just pass the `Request.Form` object into the call to `EditorWorker.LoadEditData` and let that method handle actually loading up the `EditData` object that it knows it needs to return for the attribute it's responsible for, which it can do as it knows what information should be in the posted form collection to load up its `EditData` object.

So that's where I'm at for now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10):

[TryUpdateModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460189(v=vs.98).aspx) is a generic method, and therefore attempts to infer all type information based on the [Generic Type Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172193.aspx).

From what I understand in your example above, you are always passing in a `IEditData` correct?

In effect you are saying:

```
TryUpdateModel<IEditData>(attributeEditData)
```

This is most likely the cause for not seeing any properties being set, since `IEditData` doesn't have any properties ;)

To do what you want you will probably have to create a [custom ModelBinder](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx).

As a quick code review side note, your solution seems overly complicated. I had to stare at your solution for a good while just to figure out where to start. Creating a custom model binder may solve your immediate problem, but you might be looking at a big time maintenance headache here. I'm willing to bet there is a simpler approach that will lead to fewer problems down the road.

**Based on your comments** I have changed the code around from System.Object to your IEditData interface, but everything still holds. I noticed in an earlier comment you mentioned using var because you didn't know the type until runtime. However, there is nothing magic about the var keyword. The only thing it does is give you implicit typing, but it is still statically typed.

The nice thing about MVC is that you can just pop over to Codeplex and have a look at the source for [TryUpdateModel](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61835#266451) if you want. Digging down a few layers you will eventually find a call to this internal method:

```
protected internal bool TryUpdateModel<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties, string[] excludeProperties, IDictionary<string, ValueProviderResult> valueProvider) where TModel : class {
    if (model == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
    }

    //valueProvider is passed into this internal method by
    // referencing the public ControlerBase.ValueProvider property
    if (valueProvider == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("valueProvider");
    }

    Predicate<string> propertyFilter = propertyName => BindAttribute.IsPropertyAllowed(propertyName, includeProperties, excludeProperties);

    //Binders is an internal property that can be replaced by
    // referencing the static class ModelBinders.Binders
    IModelBinder binder = Binders.GetBinder(typeof(TModel));

    ModelBindingContext bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext() {
        Model = model,
        ModelName = prefix,
        ModelState = ModelState,
        ModelType = typeof(TModel),
        PropertyFilter = propertyFilter,
        ValueProvider = valueProvider
    };
    binder.BindModel(ControllerContext, bindingContext);
    return ModelState.IsValid;
}
```

Notice the use of `typeof(TModel)` everywhere... in your case that is getting translated into `typeof(IEditData)`, which isn't very useful since it is only a marker interface. You should be able to adapt this code for your own use, making sure to use `GetType()` in order to get the actual type at runtime.

I hope this helps out!

*P.S. I've added some comments to the above code to help out a little*

Comment: Hhmmm...I see what you're saying, and see that it most likely *is* in fact my problem here. I'm not intentionally passing in an object of type `System.Object`, but based on what you've pointed out, I can see that's probably what the framework is seeing. My bigger problem is, at runtime, I don't know what type it is I'm passing in. `EditorWorker.LoadEditData` returns an `IEditData` intentionally, as it could be anything, depending on the selected attribute. I'm open to suggestions as to how to simplify the solution, but its a complex problem.